# Compile files of specific task to an additional setup file (setup.exe, files.bin) using Inno-Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

### INTRODUCTION

The author of a piracy gaming website with name **FitGirl**, releases from time to time "re-packs" of video games, that are composed by a installer made with Inno-setup.

The interesting characteristic of those kind of installers is that are component-based (or task-based, not sure), I mean that for example if a video game re-pack has audio files related to various languages, they are available to install separately, I mean that each "voice pack" is compiled in different files, so you can see: setup.exe, english.bin, spanish.bin, etc... and if one of the .bin files is missing, it does not affect the setup.exe.

### QUESTION

I would like to know how can I reproduce that in my personal installers. For example I have a program to install, with my personal config files to use for that program, then, I want to create a task to determine whether the personal settings should be installed with the program, and compile those files in another file, not inside the setup.exe. Just the same as the author of the website above does with the "voice packs" of a re-pack installer.

As an example of what I would like to do:

```
[Files]
; Public Files
Source: {app}\*; DestDir: {app}; Flags: recursesubdirs createallsubdirs ignoreversion

; Personal files (program file settings that contains sensible data of my person)
Source: {localappdata}\*; DestDir: {localappdata}; Tasks: PersonalData; Flags: recursesubdirs createallsubdirs ignoreversion

[Tasks]
Name: PersonalData; Description: Install ElektroStudios E-mail settings
```

So, in that example, I would like the files of `{localappdata}` to be compiled to an additional file, like for example: "personal_settings.bin". This way, I can distribute the installer (setup.exe) without distributing also my personal data (personal_settings.bin), and I can use the installer in my personal computer to install the files of `{localappdata}` having the "personal_settings.bin".

### RESEARCH

After decompiling a **FitGirl** installer ( of Jurassic World: Evolution ), this is the most relevant parts of the reconstructed code I get:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Jurassic World: Evolution
...

[Components]
Name: text; Description: Main game files; Types: full custom
Name: local; Description: Game language; Types: full custom
...

[Types]
Name: custom; Description: {cm:TypeCustomDesc}
Name: full; Description: {cm:TypeFullDesc}
...
```

But I feel like it is missing all... I don't get how is done this installer to have the voice packs compiled separately in .bin files additionaly to the setup.exe, and be all selectable in the setup wizard.

Comment: It would be good if the down-voter and closer will explain the reason(s).

Comment: Such and how I supposed. Please, next time try to make your vote (and closure flag) useful for me and for the community, instead of toxic for both.

Comment: I really have the bad feeling, from many time ago, that some specific user always down-votes all my threads of whatever the topic it is just for disturbing/trolling me. Maybe a moderator could analyze the situation and apply the deserved sanction/ban for that user in case I'm not wrong). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup does not support this.

So either:

- That installer uses a custom build of Inno Setup; or
- They implemented their own unpacking in Pascal Script (and they pack the file separately using their own process, when building the installer).